# TypeError: object array may be self-referencing Python3

Tags: python-3.x, robotics

```
TypeError: object array may be self-referencing
```

I tried to read this question but I didn't get much out of it.
[TypeError: object array may be self-referencing python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778732/typeerror-object-array-may-be-self-referencing-python)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example that reproduces the error you claim to have -- one that we can copy and paste in our systems and run *as is*.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself after a while, I had a calculation with numpy arrays and I did not manually specify the datatype so it turned out it was automatically set to dtype=np.object. I fixed it by specifying dtype=np.float64.

```
myarray = ([[somevalue, somevalue, somevalue],
            [somevalue, somevalue, somevalue],
            [somevalue, somevalue, somevalue]], dtype=np.float64)
```